# JavaScript: show hidden element on click in overflow-auto

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have a set of elements grouped in a parent having `overflow-auto`.

I need to scroll/place an element to the right-most when clicked if possible. This way, the previous items are auto-scrolled to the left, placing it at the end of the view.

```js
for(let i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
  document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML += `<div class='myItem margin-end-3 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center'>${i}</div>`;
}
```

```css
.myItem {
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<div id="parent" class="d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap overflow-auto my-18 py-1"></div>
```

**Example:**

Start:

[image]

After clicking "13":

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solved the issue:

Add a `click` event listner to the items and call `event.currentTarget.scrollIntoView()`.